# Flask run not recognizing python-dotenv on windows

Tags: python, flask

So I'm running python 3.7 on Windows and I have installed python-dotenv in my virtual environment as well as flask.  I have a .flaskenv file in the root of my project where I execute flask run, it looks as if python/flask is not recognizing python-dotenv .flaskenv file it ignores my parameters and states that I do not have a FLASK_APP value assigned.  This same setup works fine on a Linux workstation.  Is there something different to configure on windows to get this to work?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you figure this out?  I am going the opposite direction and have set up a cookiecutter, but it does not work after I template it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by executing `python -m flask run` instead of `flask run`. The -m allows modules to be located and executed.

Comment: (This works for the same error on a mac as well as windows)

Comment: great! this works on W10

Answer (score 0):

.flaskenv seems to be working fine on Windows 10. Have you tried creating a new file named .flaskenv, without specifying any extension, in Visual Studio Code? A .flaskenv file of FLASKENV FILE type gets automatically created. I have in there a single line FLASK_APP=yourFileName.py.
Hope this helps.